# Flutter pdf plugin long text is not going in new line

Tags: flutter, pdf

I am using a plugin

> pdf : ^3.7.1

On Using Following Code

```
pw.Text(Very Long Text,
    style: pw.TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
           ),
),
```

The very long text is not going in a new line it's going out of the bound of the page.
[image]

As you can see the text is cut after reaching the end. Even on using paragraph same happened.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because that package can't "go inside" a single widget and split it in order to make it fit the page (or, in other cases, to create a new page).
You have to either wrap the text yourself and make it a multiline widget, or split the text yourself (maybe using something like CR or LF as separator) and divide it over different widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Text in SizedBox and give it a width

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by using the softWrap property:

```
pw.Text(Very Long Text,
    softWrap: true,
    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),
),
```